# Computing an equation-based variable in SPSS with Euler's number

Tags: variables, indexing, spss, equation, equation-solving

I'm currently working with a large population dataset in SPSS, and at this stage of my analysis I would like to predict how many people are at risk of having nonalcoholic fatty liver disease (NAFLD). I have all the necessary inputs (i.e. BMI, waist circumference, GGT, triglycerides) in my dataset, but I'm struggling with inputting the actual equation itself.

For reference, this is the equation according to the original paper by Bedogni et al. (2006):

```
FLI = (e^0.953*loge (triglycerides) + 0.139*BMI + 0.718*loge (ggt) + 0.053*waist circumference - 15.745) / (1 + e^0.953*loge (triglycerides) + 0.139*BMI + 0.718*loge (ggt) + 0.053*waist circumference - 15.745) * 100
```

The constant *e* is especially bothering me - I presume it's Euler's number? If so, then what is the SPSS equivalent when computing a variable?

This is what I've tried:

```
(2.71828 ** 0.953 * LN(trig) + 0.139 * bmi + 0.718 * LN(gat) + 0.053 * waist_circ - 15.745 / (1 + 2.71828 ** 0.953 * LN(trig) + 0.139 * bmi + 0.718 * LN(ggt) + 0.053 * waist_circ - 15.745) * 100
```

While it gives a result, it doesn't correlate with the results given by this online calculator:

https://www.mdcalc.com/calc/10001/fatty-liver-index

Comment: You seem to have left 0.953 out of your formula.

Comment: Yes, that was me typing too fast. Fixed it now. Problem still remains.